# Добавление раздела к root linux

Tags: linux, файловая-система, linux-mint

У меня стоит linux mint. Кончается место в файловой системе(ФС). ОС стоит на SSD, а на HDD свободный раздел с уже готовой ФС ext4. Можно ли этот раздел добавить просто к / чтобы все дирректории (к примеру /home) использовали и исходный раздел, и новый(как ФС решит).
То есть смонтировать его не как 'постоянную флешку', на которую отдельно класть данные, а чтобы его использование было незаметно и встроено наравне с исходным разделом.

Comment: С помощью GParted пробовали?

Comment: у меня не стоит данная программа. сейчас попробую конечно, но вроде она работает с изменениями размеров разделов, а мне надо добавить к / раздел с другого диска

Comment: Именно к / вмонтировать вряд ли удастся, но к примеру перенести /home и т.д. возможно будет шанс.

Comment: На втором диске нет опции 'точка монтирования". На первом есть, а на втором нет

Comment: Надо было том держать на lvm, тогда бы это просто решалось (недавно сам добавлял терабайт к имеющемуся полутерабайтовому диску, один раздел у меня теперь 1.4Tb). В вашем же случае можно отдельные каталоги попереносить, например _/home_.

Answer (score -1):

Нет. Из разных дисков нельзя создать один раздел. Это физически разные устройства.

Comment: вопрос-то не про физическое блочное устройство, а про виртуальное. всякие там overlayfs, aufs, mhddfs. «тысячи их».

Comment: Мне не нужен 1 раздел из 2 в итоге. Мне нужно чтобы файловая система пользовалась этими разделами сама. А то можно примонтировать раздел как каталог и в нём будет только то, что ты сам туда поместишь.